# Python if no AttributeError

Tags: python, attributeerror

I have a small script that returns the title of a webpage

```
title = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(URL)).title.string
```

But not all websites specify a `<title>` tag, in which case my script returns

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'
```

Is there a way to have the `title` variable equal to the title if there is a title on the webpage?

I am tried

```
if BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url)).title.string.strip():
    print BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url)).title.string.strip()
else:
    print url
```

But it still raises the AttributeError error

Comment: havce you tried using a `try except` clause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
try:
    title = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(URL)).title.string
except AttributeError:
    title = url
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use inbuilt function `getattr` to check whether the attribute exists and if not set a default value to it.

In your case it will be like

```
title = getattr(BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(URL)).title, 'string', 'default title')
```

Check documentation for `getattr` function - https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr